# Custom query result empty on page 2

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I'm trying to filter paginated results of my custom query. 
I've got 4 posts, 3 per page, total of 2 pages. When I apply the filter while on page 1, it works. When I apply the filter while on page 2, query result is empty.

My guess is either query doesn't know which page I'm on or I got the form action="" wrong. Any hints?

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-9 m-4 pt-4 pb-4">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <label>Select option</label>
            <select name="filter_options">
                <option value="">Any</option>
                <option value="800">800</option>
                <option value="1200">1200</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
<?php
     $currentPage = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

     if (array_key_exists('filter_options', $_GET)) {
          $value = $_GET['filter_options'];
          $args = array(
              'post_type'=> 'my_custom_type',
              'paged' => $currentPage,
              'posts_per_page'=>3,
              'meta_query' => array(
                  'relation' => 'OR',
                   array(
                        'meta_key' => 'my_meta_key',
                        'value' => $value)
                    )
                );
     } else {
          $args = array(
             'post_type'=> 'my_custom_type',
             'paged' => $currentPage,
             'posts_per_page'=>3
          );
    }

    $posts = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
        while ($posts->have_posts()) {
            $posts->the_post();
            get_template_part( '/template-parts/content', 'filters');
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-md-center mt-5">    
    <div class="col-2">
            <?php echo paginate_links(array(
                'total' => $posts->max_num_pages,
                'prev_text' => 'Prev',
                'next_text' => 'Next'
            )); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you display it in frontpage? do you set any static page? if you manually type http://somedomain/somepost/page/2, what did you see?

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom dynamic page, used only for this specific query result.
The problem was form action="" being empty. $_GET parameters were sent to the same page i.e. /result-page/?filter-options=800 which is fine but while on page-2, the results were sent to /result-page/page/2/?filter-options=800.

Setting the form action="/result-page" solved the problem. Thanks.